# Finding the period with the highest rolling sum per category

Tags: r, rstudio

Here's the thing.

I have rather large set of data (1,5 million rows) that represents 40k clients and some metrics about them for each of 40+ months, so data looks more or less like this:

```
CLIENTID| MONTHID| VALUE
--------|--------|-------
client1 | month1 | value1
client1 | month2 | value2
client1 | month3 | value3
client2 | month1 | value4
client2 | month2 | value5
client3 | month1 | value6
client4 | month1 | value7
etc...
```

Not every `CLIENTID` have all `MONTHID`, many appear only in some months.

**So here is what I'm trying to do with it:**

I need to extract, for each `CLIENTID` a `X` month period of their "life" that have biggest sum of `VALUE` among all `X` month periods available in dataset.

This `X` month period is continuous in a sense that I look at concurrent months, even if there are no rows for that specific `MONTHID` for given `CLIENTID`.

**Here is a logical breakdown of how I visualized process mentally to myself:**

1. extract 1st `X` `MONTHID` period from dataset and for each `CLIENTID` sum `VALUE` to get one number for each `CLIENTID` for that period and store it with `CLIENTID`, some new `PERIODID` and summed `VALUE` of my feature.
2. by increasing starting `MONTHID` of period by one, loop trough all periods for each `CLIENTID` and replace those values in stored set if new value for given `CLIENTID` is bigger than previously stored

**So here is my question(s):**

1. Firstly: is this approach logically valid? I think it should work but maybe there is much easier solution that can be used in this scenario
2. Secondly and most importantly: How to achieve it in R? I'm still learning R language, I know how to subset data, summarize them, etc... but I'm straggling with looping functions like apply/mapply/etcpply (:P).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little difficult to test this without an idea of what your data looks like, and I can't say how fast it will be, but here's one possible solution.

Create sample data frame:

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
    CLIENTID = rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each=10), 
    MONTHID = as.vector(replicate(4, sample(1:40, 10))), 
    VALUE = sample(100:500, 40, replace = T))
```

From what you said in the question, for some CLIENTIDs there are no entries for a given MONTHID. I take it that means the value for that month is 0? In which case, it's simplest to have a data frame that represents these zero values, which we can create using `expand.grid` and `merge`.

```
clientmonths <- expand.grid(
    CLIENTID = unique(df$CLIENTID), 
    MONTHID = seq(from=min(df$MONTHID), to=max(df$MONTHID)))

df2 <- merge(clientmonths, df, all = T)

df2$VALUE[is.na(df2$VALUE)] <- 0
```

In what follows, I use the `filter` function from base-R to create a rolling sum and also use the completely unrelated `filter` function from the dplyr package...

```
library(dplyr)

getPeriodSum <- function(x, period) {
    x %>% 
    mutate(periodSUM = as.vector(stats::filter(VALUE, rep(1, period), sides=1))) %>%
    filter(periodSUM == max(periodSUM, na.rm = T)) %>%
    select(endMONTH = MONTHID, periodSUM)
}

df2 %>% arrange(MONTHID) %>% group_by(CLIENTID) %>% getPeriodSum(5)
```

This code returns a data frame with a CLIENTID column, a periodSUM column containing the maximum cumulative sum of VALUE for the specified x-month period, and an endMONTH column containing the MONTHID for the end of the x-month period. If there are ties (i.e. the same maximum value can be produced by more than one sequence of months) there will be more than one row per CLIENTID.

I use a value of 5 to find the maximum 5-month total, but you can change that to another value.

Comment: Thx, will take me some time to digest it and test it. I'll get back to You after I finish my hollidays and get back to work. Thx for the tip with expand.grid. I will have to add it to my toolbox list :)

Comment: I'm certain using expand.grid with such a large dataset is going to cause you problems, but maybe you can figure out a way to do it.

Comment: thx for chenging it to dplyr, that makes it much more readable to me :)